# how to instantiate UI image in unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, uiimage, parent-child, instantiation

I'm making 2d racing game .... and I'm using UI image in the canvas background (road) .my car and enemy cars and I have tried to instantiate enemy car with this script by attaching this script to empty gameObject then attaching the enemy prefab to the enemyCar image that in the script...but the strange thing is :the enemyCar is instantiated in the hierarchy but I can't see it in the game What is the wrong ? is the wrong related to the child and parent or what ? and how can I make that UI image a child of canvas in the script ?

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 public class Generate : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public Image enemyCar;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
     InvokeRepeating("CreateEnemy", 1f, 1.5f);
 }

 void CreateEnemy()
 {
     Instantiate(enemyCar);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new UI system UI elements can only be seen if they are children to a Canvas. Simply instantiating the element puts in the hierarchy but not under the canvas. You need to find a reference to your canvas in the seen and set its transform as a parent your Instantiated enemy. For example use this c# code.

```
var _quitmessage = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Messages/QuitMessage", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
                canvasObject = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
                _quitmessage.name = "Quit Message";
                _quitmessage.transform.SetParent(canvasObject.transform, false);
```